# Best way to find potential UTF-8 characters from an imported email

Tags: ruby

So when you view the source of an email, there are several characters in there that should be converted back to UTF-8 by the email client.

For example, in Outlook, a source email may contain `=C2=A9` which converts to the copyright symbol.

In ruby, is there a way that I can find these types of characters/patterns and convert them to HTML so that it's displayed in an HTML form? For example, taking things like `=C2=A9` and converting it into its associated HTML format `&copy;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to consider. First, the original string format using `=` is called "quoted-printable". Force UTF-8 encoding. Then, use [htmlentities](https://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlentities#encoding) to convert to HTML entities. Here is an example:

```
require 'htmlentities'
coder = HTMLEntities.new
string = '=C2=A9'.unpack("M").first.force_encoding('UTF-8')

coder.encode(string) # => "©"
coder.encode(string, :named) # => "&copy;"
```

I hope you find that helpful.

Comment: I tried that, but it does not encode `=C2=A9` to return `&copy;`. I tried it on `Repl.it`.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna I updated the answer to include converting of quoted-printable string to UTF-8 before encoding HTML entities.

Comment: Thank you. I did not think of `unpack` and `force_encoding`.

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps I can use some sort of regex to scan an entire string for these instances?

Comment: @LewlSauce Sure you can, depending on why you want to do that, it might not be necessary. e.g. `'Copyright =C2=A9 Me'.unpack("M")` will work just fine (=> `"Copyright © Me"`), you don't have to extract escaped characters before converting them.

Comment: @knugie Thanks. I'm importing email headers into an HTML form and there's no telling what's in the emails. Think I've got it figured out though. I really appreciate it!!